# Symfony2 Doctrine query implode invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have tried searching around and even the example in the Symfony2 documentation, and have been struggling with writing a query to select all blog posts by post category and to order them in descending order by Id.

However I have the following error when i run the code. Any suggestions?

```
ContextErrorException in SimpleArrayType.php line 51:
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

I am creating a blog, for learning purposes and am trying to retrieve posts from my posted table with the following columns.

```
Id |postTitle | postDescription | postContent | postCategory
```

My Entity looks like this, (showing most relevant sections)

```
 /**
* posted
*
  @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class posted
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
 */
protected $postTitle;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
 */
protected $postDescription;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500)
 */
protected $postContent;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="posted_at")
 */
protected $datePosted;


/**
 *@var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", length=250)
 */
protected $postCategory;

   /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

    /**
 * Set postCategory
 *
 * @param string $postCategory
 * @return posted
 */
public function setPostCategory($postCategory)
{
    $this->postCategory = $postCategory;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get postCategory
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPostCategory()
{
    return $this->postCategory;
}
```

My Controller looks like

```
    /**
 * this is the EPL page of posts of EPL category
 *
 * @Route("/EPL", name="eplposts")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function eplAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:posted')->findBy(array('postCategory' => 'English Premier League','id' => 'desc'));

   return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:EPLpost.html.twig',array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Your `postCategory` is configured as `simple_array` for Doctrine, which is a behavior to tell that you can have multiple values in this property. That way you will not be allowed to perform a `findBy` query (which is creating clauses like `WHERE <key> = <value>`, because the actual data of this column is an imploded array of all the values in this column

Comment: Okay thanks, I suspected it might be something to do with the array. I have it set as simple array because I am using a form with check boxes to store the post category in my Database. How would you suggest I could retrieve the data in the format above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create your own query method in the repository of your entity, for example, something like this :

```
class BoardRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByCategory($category)
    {
        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        $builder
            ->where($builder->expr()->like('p.postCategory', '%'.$category.','))
            ->orWhere($builder->expr()->like('p.postCategory', ','.$category.'%'))
        ;

        return $builder->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```